# Box-shadow transition not working

Tags: google-chrome, css, transition

I want a box shadow to appear on hover and transition to it.  I have the classes below.  The shadow appears, but without transition.

I'm looking at it in a chrome browser and can see the transition is applied within developer tools both in the hover and no-hover states.

```
.node{
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow .25s linear;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow .25s linear;
  -ms-transition: box-shadow .25s linear;
  -o-transition: box-shadow .25s linear;
  transition: box-shadow .25s linear;
}

.node:hover{
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Now here's the twist.  If I apply the transition properties to an ID that's set on the container, then it works!?  What difference does it make to set transitions on an element using an ID vs a class?

Comment: Seems to [work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/u6438/1/). Are you sure there's nothing overriding it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Sam, It seems like there is something overriding the style. Try being more specific with the selector.

For example, if you're HTML is setup like so:

```
<div class="item">
    <a class="node">Info</a>
</div>
```

Try being more specific with the selector like so:

```
.item a.node:hover {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: That does work.  Strange though, since the dev console shows everything applied in both hover/non-hover states just fine. Any idea why the dev console is lying?

Comment: Have you applied some CSS resets? If you also have a general style like

`a {...}`

I believe that would override the styling on all <a>.

Comment: Difficult to tell if you don't share your code in a fiddle or similar

Comment: Vytas, It should but I've had instances where some weird voodoo things would happen and there would be no clue in the (google chrome) console. So I'd have to assume what the problem is and test it out. I found this article helpful http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 1):

yo may to set `box-shadow` property to `0 0 0` before hover action

```
.node{box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);}
.node:hover{box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);}
```

That's all

Answer (score 0):

```
.node:hover{
box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-transition: .25s linear 0s;
-moz-transition: .25s linear 0s;
-o-transition: .25s linear 0s;
transition: .25s linear 0s
}
```

try this one. Its works.